# Haskell: How to remove a List from a List in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a first list and a second list, and I want to write a function that takes two lists and returns a list containing only those elements in the second list that do not appear in the first. And I don't want to use built-in functions. For example:

```
> removeAll [1..3] [0..10]
[0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

> removeAll "aeiou" "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"
"sprclfrglstcxpldcs"

removeAll _ [] = [] 
removeAll [] y = y

removeAll (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x==y = removeAll xs ys
    | otherwise = y:removeAll xs ys
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can always look at the source of the built-in functions, so you shouldn't count those out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty straightforward recursive definition

```
removeAll :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
removeAll _        []     = []
removeAll toRemove (x:xs) 
  | x `belongs` toRemove = removeAll toRemove xs 
  | otherwise            = x:removeAll toRemove xs 
    where belongs _ [] = False
          belongs a (y:ys)
            | a == y    = True
            | otherwise = belongs a ys
```

The `belongs` function is just the prelude defined `elem`. Since you don't want to use built-in functions you have to define it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is one simple way:

```
removeAll ignores = filter (\x -> notElem x ignores)
```

which makes use of:

- [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#filter)
- [`notElem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#notElem)

If you wanted to write it in "pure-pure" Haskell, with no auxiliary functions... well, it sounds like it would be pretty ugly since we'd need to do some sort of nested for-loop. Here's a compromise:

```
myFilter _ [] = []
myFilter pred (x:xs)
  | pred x = x : myFilter pred xs
  | otherwise = myFilter pred xs

myNotElem e [] = True
myNotElem e (x:xs)
  | e == x = False
  | otherwise = myNotElem e xs

removeAll ignores = myFilter (\x -> myNotElem x ignores)
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem of your current code is that you tried to recurse in two lists simultaneously in one function. You need to divide and conquer. If `elem` is allowed, you may write:

```
removeAll :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
removeAll _ [] = []
removeAll x (y:ys)
    | myElem y x = removeAll x ys
    | otherwise = y:removeAll x ys
```

If you do not want to use the built-in `elem` as well, you can define it similarly:

```
myElem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
myElem _ [] = False
myElem x (y:ys)
    | x == y = True
    | otherwise = myElem x ys
```